# Hide extra methods from array instances

Tags: javascript

I created an array with an event for all the mutating methods. So if you do a.push a.on('push') is fired. I did this by adding a new push to an instance of an array. Now the problem is that if you console.log or compare the array in tests the new methods show up as well. Is there a way to hide these new methods?

The code:

```
var oar = function (base) {

    var arr = base || [];
    var handlers = {};

    arr.on = function (event, callback) {
        if (typeof handlers[event] === 'undefined') {
            handlers[event] = [];
        }

        handlers[event].push(callback);
    };

    var proxy = function (method) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        var result = Array.prototype[method].apply(arr, args);

        process.nextTick(function () {
            if (typeof handlers[method] !== 'undefined') {
                handlers[method].forEach(function (handler) {
                    handler(arr);
                });
            }
        });

        return result;

    };

    [ 'pop', 'push', 'reverse', 'shift', 'sort', 'splice', 'unshift' ].forEach(function (method) {
        arr[method] = proxy.bind(null, method);
    });

    return arr;

};

module.exports = oar;
```

If you console.log the array or for example use should (a.should.eql(...)) to verify it in tests it takes in account all the proxy'd methods plus the on method.

```
 [ 
    'one',
    'two',
    on: [Function],
    pop: [Function],
    push: [Function],
    reverse: [Function],
    shift: [Function],
    sort: [Function],
    splice: [Function],
    unshift: [Function] 
]
```

If I understand correctly is that I could proxy the prototype instead but then all instances of array will have these new methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to set those properties using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which sets them as non enumerable by default :

```
Object.defineProperty(arr, method, {value: proxy.bind(null, method)});
```

Comment: `enumerable` is `false` by default.